# security related sites

Tags: security

What are some of the best Sites for Computer Security basics.

SSL, HTTPS, PKI, Authetication/Authorization, TLS, SAML, Vulnerabilities etc etc

Answer (score 3):

I like
[milw0rm](http://milw0rm.com/)

[Secunia](http://secunia.com/advisories/historic/)

[SANS Internet Storm Center; Cooperative Network Security Community ...](http://isc.sans.org/)

[GRC forums (Steve Gibson)](http://www.grc.com/discussions.htm)

[Security now](http://twit.tv/sn) podcast

[Schneier on Security](http://www.schneier.com/blog/)

[Open Web Application Security Project](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) (OWASP)

Answer (score 1):

OWASP

http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

I read...

http://www.governmentsecurity.org/

http://www.net-security.org/

[Threat Level - Wired](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/)

Answer (score 0):

http://ha.ckers.org/ for webapp related

Comment: @Erwin The question is: "What are some of the best Sites for Computer Security basics?" Links are valid answers to this type of question.